# How to check if styled box is outside of document

Tags: jquery, css

I have a click event that will show my box div at the location clicked, and centers the box to the mouse click. What I want to know is how to see if the box is outside of document. I have a js fiddle that when you click next to the edge of the document you will see part of the box is outside of the document. How can I detect when this happens?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ayxq7x45/

JS:

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){
    var boxWidth = $('.box').width();
    $('.box').css({
      top:e.pageY + 10,
      left:e.pageX - boxWidth / 2,
      display:'block'
    })
    //if box is outside of document
        //console.log(true);
});
```

Comment: document represents the DOM. How could the element be outside of it ?

Comment: class of box is position absolute. When clicked it gets the mouse location and sets the box left to where the mouse is divided half the box width. So if the document left position is 0 and you click the mouse at or around that point, the about half the box will be outside of the left view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is pretty simple:

You have to get:

- the width of the box
- the width of the viewport/document
- the Y position of the box when open

And calculate if the Y position + the width of the box are greater than the width of the viewport, if so, the Y position must be the width of the viewport - the Width of the box.

So it would be something like:

```
var boxWidth = $('.box').width();
var boxY = $('.box').offset().left;
var viewPortWidth = $(window).outerWidth();

if(boxY+boxWidth > viewPortWidth){
  $('.box').offset().left = viewPortWidth - boxWidth;
}
```